# efficient way to execute command when instructed

Tags: linux, debian

What is the best and secure way for a terminal to ping a server for a list of commands to execute every 60 secs?  For example, it could download a file (that houses the command) or query a database and then execute what is on there.

Are there more efficient/secure ways to accomplish the above?

Thanks

Comment: What definitions of "terminal" and "server" are you using?  In the *nix world "terminal" refers to a serial device that can send and receive text, usually in the form of a keyboard and text display. "Server" is used to refer to a program that other programs connect to through a communications protocol which can be on the same computer or remote. You need to provide more information about each side of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH connections which are SSL  enabled. If commands are predefined you can depend on a cron job, then you don't need to login to terminal again and again to run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it into a script:

#### commands.ssh

```
echo "This will run on the remote machine."
# Do a backup or something...
```

Then you can execute pass this file to the remote machine using:

```
ssh user@remote -i id_rsa < commands.ssh
```

I recommend using an [sshkey](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) so that you don't have to keep your login information in the commands file.

Note: make sure the permissions for the commands.ssh file are secure!

```
chmod 600 commands.ssh
```